# Filter with multiple parameters with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which I need to filter.

If the object has an active value of true then it should always be returned regardless of other factors.

If searchText is entered then the rest of the list should be filtered by this search text.

If a countrySearch is entered then the list should be filtered by this value, and also by the searchText if that is provided.

```
const searchText = 'Di';
const countrySearch = "USA";

const myArray = [
    {
        name: "Tom",
        country: "UK",
        active: true
    },
    {
        name: "Dick",
        country: "USA",
        active: false
    },
    {
        name: "Dimmon",
        country: "FR",
        active: false
    }
].filter(item => { 
    if (item.active === true) {
        return true;
    }
  if (searchText) {
    if(item.name.includes(searchText)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
});

console.log(myArray);
```

In this example the new array should contain Tom as active is true. It should contain Dick as he passes both the searchText and countrySearch test. Dimmon should not be in the new array as he passes only 1 of the searchText and countrySearch search conditions.

It is possible for me to solve this using my current approach but its getting messy with nested if statements. Also my search conditions are likely to grow in complexity overtime. Is this a good case for functional programming?

Comment: Rather than nest `if` statements, you could use `||` and `&&`.

Comment: is it OR or AND clause? i mean the result should mett all conditions or any of conditions?

Comment: `.filter( item => item.active || item.name.includes(searctText) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the expected logic you can use `active`, `OR` `countrySearch` `AND` `countrySearch` is equal to `country` `AND` `searchText` `AND` `name` `.includes()` `searchText`, `OR` `searchText` `AND` `countrySearch` is `false` `AND` `name` `.includes()` `searchText`, `OR` `searchText` is `false` `AND` `countrySearch` `AND` `countrySearch` is equal to `country`

```js
const searchText = 'Di';
const countrySearch = "USA";

const myArray = [{
      name: "Tom",
      country: "UK",
      active: true
    },
    {
      name: "Dick",
      country: "USA",
      active: false
    },
    {
      name: "Dimmon",
      country: "FR",
      active: false
    }
  ]
  .filter(({active, name, country}) =>
    active 
    || countrySearch && countrySearch === country
      && searchText && name.includes(searchText)
    || searchText && !countrySearch && name.includes(searchText)
    || !searchText && countrySearch && countrySearch === country   
  );
  
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way you can do it using [transducers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+transducers)

- an arbitrary number of filters can be used
- the input array will only be traversed a single time

```js
const comp = ( f , g ) =>
  x => f ( g ( x ) )
  
const compose = ( ...fs ) =>
  fs.reduce ( comp , x => x )
  
const append = ( xs , x ) =>
  xs.concat ( [ x ] )
  
const transduce = ( ...ts ) => xs =>
  xs.reduce ( ts.reduce ( comp ) ( append ) , [] )
  
const filterer = f =>
  k => ( acc , x ) => f ( x ) ? k ( acc , x ) : acc
  
const search = ( query , country, items ) =>
  transduce ( filterer ( x => x.active === true )
            , filterer ( x => x.name.includes ( query ) )
            , filterer ( x => x.country === country )
            ) (items)

const data0 = 
  [ { name: 'Tom'
    , country: 'UK'
    , active: true
    }
  , { name: 'Dick'
    , country: 'USA'
    , active: true
    }
  , { name: 'Dimmon'
    , country: 'FR'
    , active: false
    }
  ]

            
console.log ( search ( 'Di', 'USA', data0 ) )
// [ { name: 'Dick'
//   , country: 'USA'
//   , active: true
//   }
// ]
```

If you don't want the ceremony that comes with the generalized procedures, you can always build a completely proprietary API

```js
  
const run = ( value = [] ) =>
  ( { type : run
    , value : value
    }
  )

const filterer = f => g =>
  g && g.type === run
    ? g.value.filter ( x => f ( x ) )
    : filterer ( x => f ( x )  && g ( x ) )
    
const search = ( query , country , items ) =>
  filterer ( x => x.active === true )
           ( x => x.name.includes ( query ) )
           ( x => x.country === country )
           ( run ( items ) )

const data0 = 
  [ { name: 'Tom'
    , country: 'UK'
    , active: true
    }
  , { name: 'Dick'
    , country: 'USA'
    , active: true
    }
  , { name: 'Dimmon'
    , country: 'FR'
    , active: false
    }
  ]
            
console.log ( search ( 'Di', 'USA', data0 ) )
// [ { name: 'Dick'
//   , country: 'USA'
//   , active: true
//   }
// ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your search method, you can simplify your code as below.

First search joins conditions with OR clause. It simply looks array of objects  whose `active` property is set to `true`, **OR** name attribute contains **Di** lexem - thus all three objects match.

The second one also does the same operations but this time with **AND** clause, and result is empty array. Because none of objects are helding  both conditions at a time.

```js
const searchText = 'Di';
const countrySearch = "USA";

const myArray = [
    {
        name: "Tom",
        country: "UK",
        active: true
    },
    {
        name: "Dick",
        country: "USA",
        active: false
    },
    {
        name: "Dimmon",
        country: "FR",
        active: false
    }
]
console.log('OR')
console.log(myArray.filter(e => e.active || e.name.includes(searchText)));
console.log('AND')
console.log(myArray.filter(e => e.active && e.name.includes(searchText)));
```

Comment: Missing explanation

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and pass the `searchText` & `countrySearch`. The return from the `filter` function will be dependent on `countrySearch`

```
const searchText = 'Di';
        const countrySearch = "USA";
        const myArray = [
            {
                name: "Tom",
                country: "UK",
                active: true
            },
            {
                name: "Dick",
                country: "USA",
                active: false
            },
            {
                name: "Dimmon",
                country: "FR",
                active: false
            }
        ]
        function getFilterResult(b, c) {
            return myArray.filter(function(a, d) {
           // if countrySearch is undefined then return only active & name
           // which pass the searchText, else return where all the conditions match
                return void 0 === c ? a.active || a.name.includes(b) : 
                a.active || a.name.includes(b) && a.country === c;
            });
        };
    console.log(getFilterResult(searchText,countrySearch));
```

Answer (score 0):

> In this example the new array should contain Tom as active is true.
> It should contain Dick as he passes both the searchText and countrySearch
> test.
> Dimmon should not be in the new array as he passes only 1 of the searchText
> and countrySearch search conditions.

```js
const searchText = 'Di';
const countrySearch = "USA";

const myArray = [
{
    name: "Tom",
    country: "UK",
    active: true
},{
    name: "Dick",
    country: "USA",
    active: false
},{
    name: "Dimmon",
    country: "FR",
    active: false
}
].filter(item => item.active || (item.name.includes(searchText)
  && item.country.valueOf() === countrySearch.valueOf() ));
document.write(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Comment: *Is this a good case for functional programming?* ~ * ~ Your question has nothing to do with functional programming.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
.filter(item => { 
    if (
            (item.active === true) ||
            (searchText && item.name.includes(searchText))
    ) {
        return true;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: `(item.active === true) ||` can be also written as ` item.active ||`